Is the solution to Riemannian Newton equation necessarily on the tangent space?
To optimize a function $F(\mathbf{U})$ on a manifold with newton method, we need to solve the Riemannian Newton equation
$
\text{hess}F(\mathbf{U})[\xi_\mathbf{U}] = - \text{grad}F(\mathbf{U})
$
where the new step $\xi_\mathbf{U}$ must be on the tangent space,
$
\xi_\mathbf{U} \in T_\mathbf{U}\mathcal{M}
$
I wonder whether there are cases that the tangent space does not have a root on it, or the root lies outside the tangent space.
If so, is there any general way to find an "approximate" root on the tangent space?
The question arises as I am working on the minimization of the quadratic function
$F(\mathbf{U})=\mathbf{U^\top A}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{U^\top BU}$
with the simplex constraint
$\mathcal{M} = \{ \mathbf{U} | U_i > 0, \sum_i^d U_i = 1, \mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{R}^d \}$.
The corresponding tangent space is
$T_\mathbf{U}\mathcal{M} = \{ \xi | \sum_i^d \xi_i = 0, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d \}$.
The related information can be found in here.
I found that since the Euclidean hessian, $\mathbf{B}$, is a constant, the Riemannian Newton equation can be written in a simple linear system form
$
\left[
    \mathbf{M \odot B} + \text{diag}(\mathbf{N})
\right] \xi_\mathbf{U} = - \text{grad}F(\mathbf{U})
$
where $\mathbf{M}$ is a matrix and $\mathbf{N}$ is a vector that are known from the Riemannian and Euclidean gradient independent of $\xi_\mathbf{U}$. $\odot$ is element-wise product and $\text{diag}(\cdot)$ is the diagonal matrix constructed from a vector.
This equation can be solved by any linear solver.
In my current implementation, if my coding is correct (maybe not), the bracket on the left-hand side is found to have full rank $d$, so there is no room for the constraint equation $\sum_i^d \xi_i = 0$.
(If the bracket had rank $d-1$, I would implement the constraint equation to make it full rank.)
However, the root turns out to violate the constraint.
In other words, the obtained root is outside the tangent space, so there must be something wrong.
I expect one of these possible explanations:
(A) The root to the Riemannian Newton equation is always located somewhere on the tangent space. I found the incorrect root because there are bugs in my codes.
(B) The out-of-tangent-space root is quite common. Practically, people must somehow project the root back to the tangent space approximately.

Look up "retraction". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689946/what-is-an-euclidean-retraction-riemannian-optimization

@MarkL.Stone Thanks. I know what retraction is: When one obtains a step in the tangent space, he will retract the step to the manifold for following iterations. However, now the question is how to obtain the step in the tangent space in the first place if the root to Riemannian Newton equation is outside the tangent space.

The problem is solved.
My initial coding is incorrect.
After I removed the bug, the matrix in the bracket $\mathbf{M\odot B}+\text{diag}(\mathbf{N})$ had rank $d-1$, so there is the room for the constraint $\sum_i^d \xi_i = 0$.
However, this Riemannian hessian may be non-positive definite, so the exact solution above is very likely to lead to a saddle point.
Therefore, truncated conjugate gradient method is more robust.
